# .net api connection error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached

i have this error for max time my connection string is

i have max time of this error

and my api like this

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        //string valuess = Commanfunction.logintokencheck(user_id, token);
        try
        {                
            //if (valuess == "True")
            //{
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [nwt].[usermessage] where [to_user] = '" + user_id + "' AND [msg_user_type] ='inbox' AND [reviwe] =1 AND ([status]='active' OR [status]='keep')", sconn))
                {
                    sconn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    string x = "{\"status\":\"200ok\",\"reviewcount\":" + dt.Rows.Count;
                    // string y= serializer.Serialize(x);
                    //foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    //{
                    //    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    //    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    //    {
                    //        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    //    }
                    //    rows.Add(row);
                    //}
                    //string z = serializer.Serialize(rows);
                    return new RawJsonActionResult(x + "}");
                    //return (x + "\"countries\":" + z + "}");

                }
```

how can i resolve this error and optimize my api's. give solution

Comment: <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=53.127.121.91;Initial Catalog=nhybridtewft;User ID=sa;Password=admin;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: what is `sconn`? There's a lot of information missing here.

Comment: SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);

Answer (score 0):

Probably try defining a pool size in your connection string like following

```
<add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=53.127.121.91;  
    Initial Catalog=nhybridtewft;User ID=sa;Password=admin;  
    Integrated Security=False;Max Pool Size=1024;Pooling=true;  
    multipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

You can try increasing the number and see if the error fades away. I guess the maximum pool size you can declare is 32767.